# DSharpPlus send an embed to a specific channel?

Tags: c#, discord, embed, dsharp+

I'm new to working with discord bots and I was wondering if anybody knew a way to send embedded messages to specific channels. The only way I've found so far to send one is to use RespondAsync which just directly replies to whoever issues the command in the same channel. The purpose of my bot is to create automated link directories in read only channels and the command will just refresh them. Having trouble finding much Dsharpplus c# examples, and I'm terrible at making sense of documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
await ctx.RespondAsync(embed);
```

this is what I've been using to send my embeds for testing purposes, but like I said I'd like to send it in a way that it posts to a specified channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the `DiscordChannel` object of the channel(s) you want to send the embed. You can get the ID of the channel via right-click in Discord and "Copy ID"

```
DiscordChannel channel = await _client.GetChannelAsync(ID_OF_CHANNEL);

DiscordEmbedBuilder embed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
{
    Color = DiscordColor.SpringGreen,
    Description = "Good to see you!",
    Title = "Hello World"
};

await channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embed);
```

The `DiscordGuild` class also has `GetChannelAsync` you can use.